# Can not parse json array

Tags: jquery, json

Simple problem in Jquery - however the solution is not clear to me

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    handleJson();
});

function handleJson(){
    $.getJSON("fileList.json", function(json) {

        $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
            console.log(json.fileurls[idx]);
        });

    });
}
```

And this is my json

```
{
  "fileurls":[
    "file y 2014-09-17 10_43_40",
    "file x 2014-09-15 10_15_32"
  ]
}
```

The printed result in console is undefined

Comment: What does `console.log(json);` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this doesn't work, because you are calling fileurls[idx], but filurls IS idx.
idx is the index of the array, obj is its value.

In your JSON the index of the array is 'fileurls' and it contains the two filenames entries.

To loop through the filenames, you have to loop through the array itself, so you have to add an 2nd each loop. Try this:

```
function handleJson(){
$.getJSON(fileList.json, function(json) {
    $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {
        $.each(obj, function(idx2, obj2) {
            console.log(obj2);
        });
    });
});
```

}

Good luck
Boulder

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You do not need to iterate if want to access index wise, just write like this:</strike>

```
$.getJSON("fileList.json", function(json) {

        console.log(json.fileurls[0]);

    });
```

Your array is `json.fileurls`, `json` is single object so iterate  on `json.fileurls` :

```
$.each(json.fileurls, function(idx, obj) {

            console.log(json.fileurls[idx]);
        });
```

### Running Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5jo87475/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely due to the fact you are trying to loop each property of the json object, rather than the `fileurls` array. Try this:

```
.each(json.fileurls, function(idx, obj) {
    console.log(json.fileurls[idx]);
});
```

Though the `obj` argument is actually the value you want already, so you could make it easier like so:

```
.each(json.fileurls, function(idx, obj) {
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The OBJ will give you just "fileurls" but if you want to have the "file y 2014-09-17 10_43_40" and "file x 2014-09-15 10_15_32" elements separately you should iterate over OBJ again

```
$.getJSON("fileList.json", function(json) {

     $.each(json, function(idx, obj) {

          $.each(obj, function(count, element) {

               console.log(element);

          });
     });
});
```